# Correcting Drift and Stepped Pattern in Pressure Sensor Data

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, sensor, measurement

I’m observing drift and a stepped pattern in data from a piezoelectric pressure sensor measuring constant atmospheric pressure. the results are the following:

[image]

The data should ideally be a flat line with some noise. How can I correct these issues in real-time and/or in post-analysis?

**Edit Date: 24/03/2024**

I've updated my question following the suggestions from TimWescott to include more detailed information, aiming to get more precise answers:

(1): **Sensor Details**: The sensor I'm referring to is a piezoelectric pressure sensor, model 6001B, from Priamus. For more specific technical information, the datasheet is available here:  [Priamus 6001B Datasheet PDF](https://www.priamus.com/sites/default/files/2020-08/Data%20Sheet_Cavity%20Pressure%20Sensors_60xx_094e_Ed.%2004.20.pdf)

(2): **Measurement Units and Correction**: The time scale is seconds, with a sensor reading taken every 0.01 seconds. The unit of pressure is bars. Please note that there was a mistake in a previously shared image: at time 0 seconds, the pressure should also be 0 bars. Below is a corrected plot:

[image]

(3): **Sensor Installation and Testing Environment**: The sensor is installed in an injection mold cavity, as illustrated in the following image:

[image]

It's worth noting that the testing environment was controlled, with no significant variations in temperature, humidity, or other potential interfering variables.

**Edit Date: 26/03/2024**

**Process details**: the mold initially is open, setting the internal pressure equal to the atmospheric pressure (P atm). I then set a target injection pressure using the machine's controls, beginning the pressurization at 1 bar and maintaining it. After 1 minute, I increase the pressure to 2 bar, continuing this pattern. However, the actual pressure inside the mold, for instance in the area where the sensor is located, might be lower than the set target. This discrepancy introduces uncertainty in the real internal pressure measurements. An example illustrating this pressure increase scenario is provided here:

[image]

Comment: Get a better pressure sensor.  Seriously -- the stepwise changes is some property of the sensor or its installation, and a drift in _any_ sensor's offset is indistinguishable from a drift in the quantity being measured.  We can try to explain why this is happening, and whether it's a reasonable thing to expect for your sensor if you _edit your question_ with enough information.  Please include (1) a link to the sensor's datasheet, (2) the time and pressure scales (0 to 1.4 what?  Days?  Seconds?; 5.3 to 5.9 what?  Pascals?  Atmosphere?  Torr?, (3) installation details of the sensor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited my original question to add more information and help produce better answers.

Comment: It appears that you are misusing the sensor.  The answer to your question is "you can't".  The answers to "but why?" belong on electronics.stackexchange.com, or perhaps engineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The two biggest problems that I see are precision and drift.  Precision, because you are using a sensor designed to measure a range of $0 \cdots 6000 \mathrm{bar}$, and you are seeing a $0.1 \mathrm {bar}$ variation.  This is to be expected.  Drift, because you are using a piezoelectric sensor; this is going to be seen as a capacitor by the signal conditioning electronics, which, in turn, means that drift _is inevitable_.  If you're using their electronics, there should be a drift specification in there.

Comment: Unless you are cycling pressure from some known point to some unknown point, faster than the drift affects your reading -- that's what these sensors appear to be designed for.  Then you can use signal processing to ignore the drift.  The stepwise changes are still a problem, because you're using the very lowest part of the sensor's range -- you could filter those out, but only at the expense of a lot of delay in your sensor readings.

Comment: I really appreciate the advice and information, because I am having a hard time finding resources online that discuss these issues. For external reasons, I can only use this sensor, and I need to extract as much information as possible from it. Since my cycling pressure process takes between 5 and 10 minutes, the drift will affect my readings. Let's also assume that the process will start from some known pressure point.

Comment: Therefore, I have two questions: (1) What signal processing technique would you recommend for ignoring the drift? (2) How would you filter the stepwise changes, assuming the delay is not critical?

Comment: Can you deliberately hold your pressure at a known constant, or even bring it back to a known constant periodically?  Edit your question with this, if so.

Comment: The mold starts open, with the internal pressure equal to the atmospheric pressure (P atm). Although I can specify and maintain a target pressure using the machine's settings, the actual pressure inside the mold might be lower than this target, making the real internal pressure uncertain. More details are provided in the edit.